# Issue upon Spark Upgrade : key not found: _PYSPARK_DRIVER_CONN_INFO_PATH

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Downloaded the latest `Spark` version because of the fix for

> ERROR AsyncEventQueue:70 - Dropping event from queue appStatus.

After setting environment variables and running the same code in `PyCharm`, I'm getting this error, which I can't find a solution of.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: _PYSPARK_DRIVER_CONN_INFO_PATH
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer$.main(PythonGatewayServer.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer.main(PythonGatewayServer.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Any help?

Answer (score 4):

i met this question too. The next is what i do, hoping to help you:

**1** .  find your spark version, my spark's version is 2.4.3;

**2** .  find your pyspark version, my pyspark,version is 2.2.0;

**3** .  reinstall your pyspark as same as the spark's version

```
pip install pyspark==2.4.3
```

Then everything is ok. Hope to help you.

Answer (score 2):

I am using Pyspark 2.3.1 with pycharm 2018.1.4 and facing similar issue on my windows machine.
When I run this python file using spark-submit, it get executed successfully.

I have followed below steps

1. Created a new project in pycharm, lets call it Demo
2. Goto Settings->Project:Demo->Project Interpreter. Make sure project interpreter is python 2.7
3. Goto Settings->Project:Demo->Project Structure. Add Content Root. 
   I have added two content root one pointing to directory where content of apache spark is present and the other location is of py4j-0.10.7.src.zip
   In my case these locations are

> C:\apache-spark

and

> C:\apache-spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip

4. Created new `python` file(Demo1.py) and pasted below content inside it.

   `from pyspark import SparkContext`

   `sc = SparkContext(master="local", appName="Spark Demo")`

   `rdd = sc.textFile("C:/apache-spark/README.md")`

   `wordsRDD = rdd.flatMap(lambda words: words.split(" "))`

   `wordsRDD = wordsRDD.map(lambda word: (word, 1))`

   `wordsCount = wordsRDD.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x+y)`

   `print wordsCount.collect()`

Running this python file on pycharm gives below error

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not
>   found: _PYSPARK_DRIVER_CONN_INFO_PATH

Where as same program when executed from command prompt yields correct result.

`C:\Users\manish>spark-submit C:\Demo\demo1.py`

Any suggestions to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add your experience/observations as a comment not as an answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have had a similar exception. My problem was running jupyter and spark with different users. When I run them with the same user problem is solved.

**Details;**

When I updated spark from v2.2.0 to v2.3.1 then run the Jupyter notebook, the error log was as follows;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: _PYSPARK_DRIVER_CONN_INFO_PATH
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.default(MapLike.scala:228)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.default(Map.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.MapLike$class.apply(MapLike.scala:141)
    at scala.collection.AbstractMap.apply(Map.scala:59)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer$.main(PythonGatewayServer.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonGatewayServer.main(PythonGatewayServer.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:894)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:228)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

When I googling I encountered the following link;
[spark-commits mailing list archives](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/spark-commits/201805.mbox/%3C5ac10a27fbfd43fa83fb85f18ee29ddb@git.apache.org%3E) 
In the code

```
/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/api/python/PythonGatewayServer.scala
```

there is a change

```
+    // Communicate the connection information back to the python process by writing the
+    // information in the requested file. This needs to match the read side in java_gateway.py.
+    val connectionInfoPath = new File(sys.env("_PYSPARK_DRIVER_CONN_INFO_PATH"))
+    val tmpPath = Files.createTempFile(connectionInfoPath.getParentFile().toPath(),
+      "connection", ".info").toFile()
```

According to this change it is created a temp dir and a file in it. My problem was running jupyter and spark with different users. Because of this I think the process could not created the temp file. When I run them with the same user problem solved. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and it ended up being the pyspark code I was importing/running from PyCharm was still the spark 2.2 install instead of the spark 2.3 installation that I had updated `SPARK_HOME` to point to.

Specifically, I added spark-2.2 to my PyCharm project structure and then marked it's python folder a "Sources" so PyCharm would recognize all it's symbols.  So the PyCharm code was importing from there, instead of spark-2.3, and the older code didn't set the `_PYSPARK_DRIVER_CONN_INFO_PATH` environment variable.

If Vezir's answer didn't fix your case, try tracing into the creation SparkContext and compare carefully the path that is being read from as opposed to path of your spark install.  Similarly, if you installed pyspark into your python project via pip, make sure you installed 2.3.1 to match your installed spark version.

Comment: I got your answer at a very high level, but it is not clear to me. I am using a machine where my PycCharm Project Interpreter is set to None, as it is inferring from the bash_profile configuration. My SPARK_HOME is set to 2.3.1 path, but still this issue persists.

Comment: Try putting a break point in your driver in pycharm and then stepping into the SparkContext  creation.  At that point, look to see if the file you are in is really part of your spark 2.3 install to confirm you are pointed at the right one.

Comment: Fixed that issue by uninstalling py4j and then installing the same where version==2.3.0 compatible and then setting a few path and all made it work. Facing a new challenge now, can you see if you can help there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52071854/rdd-collect-issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you are running spark 2.3.1 jars with an older version of pyspark (eg: 2.3.0)